# can .net read and print postscript fonts

Tags: gdi, postscript

Before I spend hours learning how to design a custom font (I have FontForge), I need to ask a very basic question. Can vb.net (GDI) read and print a custom font with different colored glyphs?

I need a custom font where each character shape is basically the same but colored differently for each character glyph. Yes, sounds strange but it's what's needed.

I've done some research and found that PostScript type 3 is able to contain color information yet reading on, find that there is very little support for postscript with nothing for Windows. (I think that's what I read. It's all so sketchy) I'm here because the information appears to be fairly old. I'm hoping someone has more current information.

I don't want to render the font on a web page. It must be able to be rendered in a Rich textbox and output to a PDF file or GDI output. I code in vb.net 2010 with no c#.

I received great help here before and look forward to your answers.

Comment: I don't think this is a VB.NET-specific question (in the overwhelming majority of cases, C# code can be converted to the VB.NET equivalent).  The central question is: can a RichTextbox use the color information in a Postscript Level 3 font.

Comment: Is this in WPF or in WinForms? Are you sure you need a RichTextbox and not a simple TextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PostScript type 3 font is a different beast to a type 1 font. A type 3 font can contain arbitrary PostScript while a type 1 font is a binary format with strict limits on what can be represented, and contains no real PostScript.

In order to render a type 3 font, the engine would require a full PostScript interpreter, and to the best of my knowledge no version of Windows includes such a thing.

I don't believe you can use a PostScript type 3 font with any Windows API.